# Retrieve List of unknown type from PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

I have a class with a list defined.

```
class Program
{          
      public List<string> list { get; set; }
};
```

I need to retrieve this list using PropertyInfo , but the issue is that the List can be of any type (here string). How do I extract the values of the list using propertyinfo as getValue() doesn't return me a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to `IList` then use a loop:

```
var myList = (IList)typeof(Program)
                    .GetProperty("list")
                    .GetValue(yourInstance);
```

If you don't know the actual type of your list, that's all you can do.If you know the type at *compile-time*, then you can cast it to `IList<T>`

Comment: not helping out...converting to IList shows error 
"Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>' requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: You need `using System.Collections;`